# C++ build automation in Jenkins (VS 2008 code)

Tags: c++, jenkins, makefile

We are trying to automate the C++ (VS 2008) code build using Jenkins. I have used Cmake with Unix makefiles as the generator and have completed generating the makefile but post that when i use make all from the build directory.
Now make all with "all" as that is the default target, there is no executable that gets generated and the Jenkins jobs shows as success but i cannot see the executable in any of the folders in the workspace.
I have tried to wipe out workspace and then executed still the build fails.
Is there something obvious that i have missed. Please help me..

Thanks
Shalini

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember to provide as much information as possible when posting a question. This includes any sample code/errors you have received.

Comment: Does the build work in your usual environment (using cmake on posix), but fail in the jenkins environment? You should be able to capture the output, and that will tell you what is missing.

Comment: This is how I'd do it: First forget Jenkins, just write a .bat file which you can run from an ordinary cmd.exe terminal, which does the build. Then just run that .bat from Jenkins job. Also, why cmake for a VS project? I'd stick to "official" MS way of doing command line builds. The .bat file probably just sets up the environment and runs the build tool, so it is probably very short, maybe just two lines (import environment, start build).

Comment: Other than that, the question doesn't providr enough information to be answerable. So the actual problem is not Jenkins job at all, it's the build? I'd edit the title concentrate on that (suggestion if I didn't misunderstand: "cmake build of VS2008 project does not produce .exe") and add details about that.